# How to exit ssh connection on administratively prohibited error

Tags: ssh

For `ssh -N -L port:host:port` I can use `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` to fail early when forwarding the port fails.

However, this doesn't seem to work when forwarding that specific port is forbidden (e.g. a that port was not allowed on the server with `PermitOpen`).

In that case I get:

`channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`

How can I fail when that happens?

Comment: There were some improvements in OpenSSH 7.5p1 in the port forwarding. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I'm using `OpenSSH_7.4p`; I should retry with 7.5.